# Illustrate how the 1st, 2nd and 3rd chunks of memory are allocated and linked in the program

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *first, *second, *third;
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("usage: ./q1 str\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    first  = (char*)malloc(660);
    second = (char*)malloc(220);
    third  = (char*)malloc(120);
    strcpy(second, argv[1]);
    printf("locations of the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd memory trunks are %p, %p, %p \n", first, second, third);
    printf("contents of the 2nd memory trunk are %s\n", second);
    free(first);
    free(second);
    free(third);
}
```

As I'm new to C when I compile this program it is only printing "usage: ./q1 str." According to the C language, this program is ended at exit(1). Does this mean that the 1st, 2nd and 3rd chunks of memory are allocated and linked into the program? If they are allocated and linked pls illustrate how they are allocated?
 Workout the number of bytes needed for each memory chunk and the values in the memory chunk header.What does this mean?

Comment: This seems to be a homework question. We are not here to do this for you. Read [ask] what you are expected to provide and which questions are welcome and which not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It prints that because of this code block:

```
if (argc < 2)
{
   printf("usage: ./q1 str\n");
   exit(1);
}
```

which means that you are executing the program like `./q1`, where you should follow the usage instructions instead.

> Does this mean that the 1st, 2nd and 3rd chunks of memory are allocated and linked into the program?

*No*! Your program executed `exit(1)`, thus it's terminated and the rest of the code (after `exit()` won't be executed.

Answer (score 0):

If you run your program as `./q1 mystr`, it will work. You need to pass a command line argument which is accepted by `argv` and is stored in the second element of that array.

Answer (score -1):

If exit(1); line executed then it will return from main with error code of 1 which indicates that the program not successfully executed, so the main function is not executed to the end, and no memory allocated.

The malloc explanation could be found here:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/